# Highcharts: how do I format the x-axis so the actual date/time from the table appears for each y

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Highcharts noob here, making a bit of progress.
Using a basic example from HC, I have this partly working but:
a) how do I format the x-axis so the actual date/time from the table appears for each y?
b) how do I make that date show in the tool-tip?
SO tells me I am trying to paste too much code and not enough discussion here so I have put it all on jsfiddle. (Apologies if I haven't learned how to work with this problem in posting.)

Partial code for only the highcharts js; data table & html can be seen on the fiddle:

```
<html>
<head>
(snip: see fiddle for all the JS headers)
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            Highcharts.chart('container', {
                data: {
                    table: document.getElementById('datatable'),
                    startRow: 0,
                    endRow: 10
                },              
                chart: {
                    type: 'spline'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    type: 'datetime',
                    labels: {
                    formatter: function() {
                    return Highcharts.dateFormat('%a, %e-%b; %H:%M', this.value);
                      }
                    }
                  },
                title: {
                    text: 'Tides for: Cundy Harbor, New Meadows River, Casco Bay, Maine'
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                      text: 'Height of tide<br>in feet.'
                        },
                        gridLineColor: '#197F07',
                        gridLineWidth: 0,
                        lineWidth:1,
                        plotLines: [{
                            color: '#FF0000',
                            width: 1,
                            value: 0
                    }]
                },
                tooltip: {
                    formatter: function() {
                        return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
                            this.point.y + ' ft.<br>' + this.point.name;
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;"> </div>
<div>
    <table id="datatable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Test</th>
                <th>Height of Tide</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
<tr><th>Monday, Sep 23 2019 18:32</th><td>9.4</td></tr>
<tr><th>Tuesday, Sep 24 2019 01:01</th><td>0.5</td></tr>
<tr><th>Tuesday, Sep 24 2019 07:20</th><td>8.3</td></tr>
<tr><th>Tuesday, Sep 24 2019 13:17</th><td>1.0</td></tr>
<tr><th>Tuesday, Sep 24 2019 19:38</th><td>9.7</td></tr>
<tr><th>Wednesday, Sep 25 2019 02:05</th><td>0.1</td></tr>
<tr><th>Wednesday, Sep 25 2019 08:24</th><td>8.8</td></tr>
<tr><th>Wednesday, Sep 25 2019 14:21</th><td>0.6</td></tr>
<tr><th>Wednesday, Sep 25 2019 20:41</th><td>10.1</td></tr>
<tr><th>Thursday, Sep 26 2019 03:05</th><td>-0.4</td></tr>
<tr><th>Thursday, Sep 26 2019 09:22</th><td>9.4</td></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
``

[jsfiddle here][1]

  [1]: https://jsfiddle.net/splobsterman/nzd851au/5/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case `category` axis type seems to be a better choice:

```
xAxis: {
    type: 'category'
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/1qv5b48o/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.type